# Smart TV not finding apps (from Ireland to UK)

Tags: smart-tv

I have a Sony Bravia 4K (2017) and I have moved from Ireland to the UK. While my Play Store is correctly set to UK, I cannot see/install basic apps like the BBC iPlayer. If I check the Play Store on the web, it tells me that the apps are not compatible.

I checked tutorials and they say to try "network -> refresh Internet content", but I couldn't find the button under network.

Any tips?

Comment: If your TV is running Android, download a browser such opera, google chrome or UC browser, in settings turn on "unknown sources", then go to any of the app's site like https://terrariumtvforpc.com/.

Comment: Thanks but actually I'm wondering why I can't access official apps from the store

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The TV updated itself and then managed to access the UK Google Play Store. Problem solved.